# Coverage Integration tests IntelliJ on Wildfly

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-coverage

I would like to verify the code coverage of my integration tests. I have implemented some REST-Services and deployed them on Wildly 9.0.2. Then I configured the coverage in IntelliJ with IDEA Coverage Runner for tracing support. When I now start Wildfly with coverage the deployment of the war fails with the following strack trace:

```
16:20:53,103 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:163)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/rt/coverage/data/ProjectData
at de.akquinet.ats.myservice.rest.services.MyUpdateService.<clinit>(MyUpdateService.java)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.jboss.invocation.proxy.AbstractProxyFactory.afterClassLoad(AbstractProxyFactory.java:95)
at org.jboss.invocation.proxy.AbstractClassFactory.defineClass(AbstractClassFactory.java:166)
at org.jboss.invocation.proxy.AbstractProxyFactory.getCachedMethods(AbstractProxyFactory.java:150)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateless.StatelessComponentDescription$3.configure(StatelessComponentDescription.java:150)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.DefaultComponentViewConfigurator.configure(DefaultComponentViewConfigurator.java:67)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:156)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.rt.coverage.data.ProjectData from [Module "deployment.myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
... 15 more

    16:20:53,106 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/rt/coverage/data/ProjectData
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.rt.coverage.data.ProjectData from [Module \"deployment.myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".batch.environment is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".beanmanager]"
    ]
}
    16:20:53,107 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/rt/coverage/data/ProjectData
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.rt.coverage.data.ProjectData from [Module \"deployment.myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".batch.environment is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"myservice-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".beanmanager]"
    ]
}
```

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2
Build #IU-145.972, built on May 14, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b162 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

I am fully aware of what a ClassNotFoundException is and usually know what to do then, but here I am stuck...

Can anybody help please?

Comment: Same thing here: IntelliJ 2016.1.3, JRE 1.8.0_91      Are you also using Ubuntu as OS?

Comment: No, I am using OS X El Capitan (Version 10.11.5 (15F34))

Comment: I managed to get Coverage working by selecting a different coverage runner in the run-settings on Code Coverage tab.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, it is not posible to use IntelliJ IDEA coverage agent, because *org.wildfly.arquillian:wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded:2.0.0.Final* doesn't have any property for setting *System Packages* (*jboss.modules.system.pkgs* system property).

The only way to use IntelliJ IDEA coverage agent is modifying *EmbeddedContainerConfiguration* and *EmbeddedDeployableContainer* classes, and then, you must use these customized classes.

I alredy made a pull request, i hope the new version will be available very soon.

```
public class EmbeddedContainerConfiguration extends CommonContainerConfiguration {

    private String systemPackages = System.getProperty("jboss.modules.system.pkgs");

    public String getSystemPackages() {
        return systemPackages;
    }

    public void setSystemPackages(String systemPackages) {
        this.systemPackages = systemPackages;
    }

    public String[] getSystemPackagesArray() {
        return (systemPackages == null || systemPackages.isEmpty()) ? null : systemPackages.split(",");
    }

}


public final class EmbeddedDeployableContainer extends CommonDeployableContainer<EmbeddedContainerConfiguration> {

    @Override
    public void setup(final EmbeddedContainerConfiguration config) {
        super.setup(config);
        if (config.getCleanServerBaseDir() != null) {
            SecurityActions.setSystemProperty(EmbeddedStandaloneServerFactory.JBOSS_EMBEDDED_ROOT, config.getCleanServerBaseDir());
        }
        final String[] cmdArgs = getCommandArgs(config);
        server = EmbeddedProcessFactory.createStandaloneServer(config.getJbossHome(), config.getModulePath(), config.getSystemPackagesArray(), cmdArgs);
    }

}
```